# A strange minor problem in moving a picture from a box to another

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapp

Hey Guys.
I am having this simple line of code:

```
Image1.Image = vImage.Image
```

Image1 is a picture box in child window and vImage is a picture box in parent window. When I open the child window for the first time, I see a complete blank picture in Image1 while at the same time vImage is having a picture on it. When I ***Hide*** and reopen it again It has the picture on it. What is the problem and how can I fix it in my Code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add `Me.Refresh()` after that statement. 
This will call the Paint-events (so does hiding and showing your Form.

Comment: Did not help, any other solution?

Comment: Thanks but when I added this to my code it is not working also

Comment: When I add Me.Hide() and Me.Show() to it, it works fine but It will appear with a blink, how can i avoid that? do you know?

Comment: Try Image1.Invalidate() or a combination of both. Not sure if this will work, but just give it a try.

Comment: @Faulty Orc Did Invalidate() work? Or did you find another solution?