# Resources related to Hiding and showing a windows form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapp

I have a form which has a picturebox and after clicking on a button another form will appear with a picture box containing the exact same picture. 
I use this line of code:

```
Image1.Image = vImage.Image
```

The thing is after I do this i need to hide the form and show it again to be able to see the changes. I cause me a blink for user which I want to avoid or do an equivalent of hiding and showing a form. How is it possible, the code looks like this:

```
Public Sub UpdatePhoto(ByVal FullName As String, ByVal vImage As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox)
timAnimate.Enabled = False
Me.Text = FullName
Image1.Image = vImage.Image
Me.Refresh()
Me.Hide()
Me.Show()
Image1.Visible = True
Call ShowTheWindow()
```

End Sub

Comment: Sometimes it takes a while.  Also you shouldn't post multiple questions that are the same( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117371/how-to-paint-our-changes-in-runtime-before-its-being-viewe-by-user and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117686/repainting-the-controls-without-flicker)

Comment: @TonyAbrams And you can add http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116556/a-strange-minor-problem-in-moving-a-picture-from-a-box-to-another to the list...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite following why you need to hide and show the form. Are you just trying to get the form to refresh? If so, just call:

```
Application.DoEvents()
```

or else you can try invalidating your control:

```
Image1.Invalidate()
```

That should cause your form to update. You shouldn't need to hide and show again. If this isn't your issue, let me know in more detail what your problem is.