# How to paint our changes in runtime before its being viewe by user

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapp

I am having a windows form that whenever I want its controls like picturebox update normally I need to hide it and show it to let the cahnges happen. This causes a blink which I want to avoid.

Does anybody know what are my options?
It is a picture box from form1 being copied to form2 and let the user see the changes.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116868/resources-related-to-hiding-and-showing-a-windows-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can you not change the control's attributes without hiding it?

Some options:

1. Don't hide the controls before changing them.
2. Show a loading animation overlay for the controls being updated (or the entire form if you are updating more than just a few).
3. I'm not quite sure exactly what you're trying to do, but [double buffering](https://web.archive.org/web/20140811193726/http://bobpowell.net/doublebuffer.aspx) may help you out.

If these options don't help, please describe your issue in more detail and I will try to provide assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but, instead of hiding the picturebox, you can try:

```
PictureBox.Invalidate();
```

after you copy the picturebox