# repainting the controls without flicker

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapp

How can we repaint our controls at run-time without flicker (hiding them first and showing them afterwards)?

Thank you

Comment: call Refresh() on the controls?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220100/how-do-i-enable-double-buffering-of-a-control-using-c-window-forms

Comment: @rene does not work it is suppose to copy an image in picturebox to another one in different form but it needs a hide and show to work propoerly.

Comment: maybe share a simple code sample that demonstrates the behavior. Currently we are guessing

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116868/resources-related-to-hiding-and-showing-a-windows-form

Answer (score 1):

Use **[double buffering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b367a457.aspx)**.

Comment: My issue is lot more simpler: a copy of image from one form to another. that's it and the image is not that fancy!

Comment: @Faulty Orc, I don't see how the simplicity (of what?) factor could change anything. Have you just tried to set DoubleBuffered property of concerned controls to true and see what happens? Otherwise, as @Rene said, you'd need to provide more details/code snippets of what you are doing exactly (preferably by updating your question).